# Return missing values in google app engine query

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In google app engine, say I have a Parent and a Child Entity:

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):
    pass
class Child(ndb.Model):
    parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed = True)
    ... other properties I don't need to fetch ...
```

I have a list of parents' keys, say `parents_list`, and I'm trying to answer efficiently: what parent in parents_list has a child.

Ideally, I would run this query:

```
children_list = Child.query().filter(Child.parent_key = parents_list).fetch(projection = 'parent_key')
```

It does not work because of the projection property (parent_key) being in the equality filter. So I would have to retrieve all properties, which seems inefficient.

Is there a way to efficiently solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your child model should actually be

```
    class Child(ndb.Model):
        parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Parent", indexed = True)
```

If you were doing this in Python2, you could use an [ndb_tasklet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) (see code below; note that I haven't executed this code myself so it's not guaranteed to work; it's just here to serve as a guide but I have used tasklets in the past before). If python3, try and create async queries

```
    class Parent(ndb.Model):

        @classmethod
        def parentsWithChildren(cls, parents_list):
        
            @ndb.tasklet
            def child_callback(parent_key):
                q = Child.query(Child.parent_key == parent_key)
                output = yield q.fetch_async(projection = 'parent_key')

                raise ndb.Return ((parentKey, output))

            # For each key in parents_list, invoke the callback - child_callback which returns a result only if the parent_key matches
            # ndb.tasklet is asynchronous so code is run in parallel
            final_output = [ child_callback(a) for a in parents_list]

            return final_output
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm using python3, loop of async queries is a good idea, it might be of comparable speed to batch.