# Aynchronous Google Datastore Calls in a Python FastAPI Application

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an application using **FastAPI** hosted on **Google Cloud Run**. A vital part of this application involves a series of read/write operations using **Google Datastore**. I've observed that these operations, particularly the ones executed in a loop, are becoming a performance bottleneck.

Here's a simplified snippet of the code:

```
# Some function calls omitted for brevity
@staticmethod
def get_single_widget(request_data, widget_id, user_profile, support_event_urls, shuffle, existing_items_ids):
    # Fetch widget data, perform some operations
    return widget

@staticmethod
async def get_recommendation_widgets(request_data: RequestData, support_event_urls, shuffle):
    widgets = {}
    try:
        # Other function calls
        existing_items_ids = []
        for widget_id in request_data.widget_ids:
            widget = RecommendService.get_single_widget(request_data, widget_id, user_profile,
                                                        support_event_urls, shuffle, existing_items_ids)
            widgets[widget_id] = widget
    except Exception as e:
        widgets['error'] = 'An Error occurred in: ' + request_data.url + ' ' + str(e)
        raise e
    return widgets
```

I have explored the possibility of making these operations asynchronous using *`asyncio`*, but it seems that **Google Datastore** does not support `parallel` operations and its methods are blocking, which limits the potential performance gains.

My question is twofold:

1. Considering the limitations of **Google Datastore**, how can I
   effectively make these Datastore operations non-blocking and implement the `async` call and improve the overall speed of my **FastAPI** application?
2. In the context of a resource-limited environment like **Google Cloud
   Run**, what strategies would you recommend to handle high read/write
   operations with Google Datastore and optimize the performance of my
   application?

I'm open to any advice, best practices, or alternative approaches that can help optimize the performance of these Google Datastore operations and enhance the overall efficiency of my **FastAPI** application.

> Already applied to the cache and cannot change or update the database due to code complexity I want mainly to make the parallel call works well

Thank you in advance for your insights!

Comment: Have you checked with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni What can I benefit from?

Comment: As per this [Github Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-datastore/issues/2) Google Datastore's client library for Python does not provide asynchronous support. You may add plus one there. And you may use [Batch operations](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices#api_calls) instead of single operations to handle high read/write operations with Google Datastore.

Comment: Check if [tasklets](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/tasklets.html?highlight=tasklet) will work for you but it would require switching to the ndb library. You can find an example in this [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68956723/15211203)

Comment: @NoCommandLine are there any limitations or cons for switching from client library to ndb?

Comment: Not that I know of. Personally, I prefer using the ndb library because I think it's easier to use - it enforces value type (integer, datetime, string, etc), enforces required field, you can use tasklets, you write less code